# Hibernate 5 showing error in glassfish 3.1 server

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

I am using `Hibernate 5`,`java 1.7` and `glassfish 3.1 server`.

I have Implement a sample `program` for fetching records from DB with includes above stuff.

when I run this `program` on `Apache tomcat server` that working fine.

But when I am try to run same program on `glassfish server` then that shows following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

I dont understand what wrongs with me. Please some body help me for solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish 3.1 supports JPA 2.0 and you are trying to use a feature introduced in JPA 2.1, hence this error. You can fix this by either downgrading JPA provider, or upgrading GlassFish to match the JPA provider.

Comment: I am just changed JPA 2.1 to JPA 2.0 but issue is still there!

Comment: Now showing "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery" This error

Comment: You are right its was JPA issue.Now it get solved! thank you very much.